# (React Native) Modal will be shown with each users only one time when a user open this App first

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am struggling to understand "AsyncStorage".
It's difficult to understand this for me because I am a junior engineer now.
But I wanna know how to keep some data inside local device user has.

Where can I use

```
 _storeData = async () => {
   try {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key',  'I like to save 
    it.');
  } catch (error) {
   // Error saving data
 }
}
```

and

```
  _retrieveData = async () => {
   try {
   const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
   if (value !== null) {
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
 } catch (error) {
   // Error retrieving data
 }
}
```

By the way, in my App, I try to make some forms which user input some data into but each user can save these data on each form and then if a user would change document user input before, he can change it.

In addition to this, user's data is on firebase firestore.

Comment: so question is "Modal will be shown with each users only one time when a user open this App first ?". I think you need add this part in your question content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example to achieve "Open modal first time app run"

```
class ModalExample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    state = {
      modalVisible: false,
    };
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  checkIfNeedOpenModal = async () => {
    try {
      const isFirstOpen = await AsyncStorage.getItem('IS_FIRST_OPEN');
      if (!isFirstOpen || isFirstOpen !== 'true') { // Check if key IS_FIRST_OPEN doesnt have value or not 'true'
        // isFirstOpen is null or not 'true' so this is first time app open

        this.setModalVisible(true)
      }
     } catch (error) {
       // Error retrieving data
     }
  }

  saveModalOpen = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('IS_FIRST_OPEN', 'true');
    } catch (error) {
      // Error saving data
    }
  }
  onModalShow = () => {
    this.saveModalOpen()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkIfNeedOpenModal()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onShow={this.onModalShow}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Maybe I did complete that for your support.
By the way, I am wondering how to check or refresh this state? 
Because, I wanna check these modal many times while I am creating this App.

Comment: I think you just need clear data or uninstall and reinstall to see modal again. But most easy way is commend line `await AsyncStorage.setItem('IS_FIRST_OPEN', 'true');` in `saveModalOpen` and uncomment when you finish testing.
If my answer correct please upvote and mark as correct. thanks

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I could do that after reset setting on iOS simulator.
However, I couldn't do that comment ```await AsyncStorage.setItem('IS_FIRST_OPEN', 'true');``` out.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue of having my modal flash / display for a second while the state was being read. Appreciate your work.